# Can Onboard SDK give raw pseudo-range and Carrier phase measurement and Ephemeris data?

Tags: gps, dji-sdk, imu

I am wonder if the Onboard SDK offer raw pseudo-range, carrier phase measurement and Broadcasted emphemeris.

I have seen the API mention RTK solution but I need to get my own solution from raw measurement and raw IMU measurement from gyroscope and accelerometer and the GPS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At present,DJI Onboard SDK doesn't support this function. If you want them to develop it, you can fill this [feedback ticket](https://formcrafts.com/a/dji-developer-feedback-en) to inform them